# SQL Server vs. Access SQL User Input

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to create a user determined statistic into SSMS?

For example, if I wanted to have the user input an end and start date and the query print the data from this date range, how would I do this (if possible)?

`WHERE table.date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate`

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

My complete code is:

`SELECT [id], [state], [CitationsReceived], [date]
FROM table
WHERE table.date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate`

My columns are id, state, CitationsReceived, date. I know that in Access SQL, I could type @StartDate and @EndDate without having those columns and it would create a user input which assigned the two entered dates to Start and EndDate. Is there any way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: If you've defined `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` properly as user variables, then I think your query should be completely valid in SQL Server.

Comment: You need client software for your user to use.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  Remember that while MS Access is both a database and a front end for the user, SQL Server is *just a database*.  That means the user interface all has to be programmed in whatever language you're using.

Comment: You can use SSRS for doing it

Comment: @nola94 Make an effort and write exactly what you want using the appropriate words, and describe better what "doesn't seem to work". If you want a kind of user interface to accept parameters, write exactly so. It's absolutely not clear what do you mean saying "statistic" and also "does not work" says nothing, does it produce an error? Does it give you incorrect answer? Where do you execute this code and what do you expect from it?

Comment: What I've got is a list of citations that my friends and I have all received (it sounds weird but its part of a discussion). I want to be able to have a box pop up when anyone runs the query that will say "Enter the start date" and "Enter the end date" (I don't have this in the code above because I was going to worry about that later). Right now my code above gives me an error saying @Start/EndDate are not defined. I don't know how to define them to get what I want, and I've also tried putting them in quotes and it tells me it can't find @Start/EndDate. I basically want it to do as Access

Comment: when you run a query in Access and the boxes pop up and ask you for the parameters in mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. Your syntax if fine, but you'll need to declare your parameters (@StartDate, etc) before the query. For example:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '2017-05-01'
```

Comment: Downvoted.  This doesn't answer the question which is about user input.

Comment: @DanBracuk, I understand you position, but I am least giving this person a starting point which is how to make the query work using parameters. Perhaps is it not "the answer", but it is useful.

Comment: The question here is not clear, not the answer. "I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work." says nothing about WHAT does not work. If it shows the error message about variables that are not declared, this answer helps

Comment: The questions are: "Is it possible to create a user determined statistic into SSMS?"  and "Is there any way to do this in SQL Server?" To which the answer is "Yes, by first creating/declaring a parameter"

Comment: This helps, but I don't want to have to go into my code every time and change my date (the people using what I'm making don't know how to do that). I want two boxes to pop up (or something similar) like in Access that asks for the user input -- I'm just not sure if this is possible with SQL Server...

Comment: @nola94, you can leave off the "= '2017-05-01", but SSMS/SQL Server are just platforms to write your SQL. As DanBracuk and Seupupic mentioned, you will need someway for the users to interact with your report...like SSRS.